# Mass mysql insert array of arrays in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have an array of arrays like this:

[image: array]

I want to insert every array like a row in mysql.
And position[0] column type, position[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG1re.png) column date, position[2] info.

The project is in laravel 5.7 but I think that in php it can be done?

*Thanks !!!!!*

Comment: Could you provide more information? like an example of your array, what have you tried so far, where is the error? etc. Check this guide to learn [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to perform a mass assignment? If you do so you should read the documentation:
[Mass Assignment Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment)

---

Update: Well if you really wanna insert a array of information on a single column, you should convert the array to a json format.

```
json_encode($array_name);
```

But you probably should create another table.

Comment: thanks !! I think with mass assignment i can do it !!

Answer (score 0):

My array is stored in $logs and with this foreach and mass assignment works fine!!

Controller code:

```
foreach ($logs as $key => $value) {
        App\Log::create(['type' => $value[0], 'date' => $value[1], 'info' => $value[2]]);
      }
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Log extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'type', 'date', 'info', 'extra',
  ];

  public $timestamps = false;
}
```